# CentOS virtual host Server DNS could not be found

Tags: centos, virtualhost, host

I want to deploy my project in virtual host in CentOS running server. I have this

```
<Directory />
#change value of next line from none to all
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName project.com
ServerAlias www.project.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project

<Directory /var/www/html/project>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the `httpd.conf` in the `/etc/httpd/conf` folder I also have this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
#127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost host.server4-245.com
#::1          localhost.localdomain localhost host.server4-245.com
192.168.1.97   www.project.com
127.0.0.1      www.project.com
```

In the `hosts` in the `/etc` folder but when i try to access http://project.com/ in the browser I get :

> This site can’t be reached
>
> project.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
>   Search Google for project
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

after altering this I restarted the httpd using

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

When I do this in ubuntu I happened to do one step that I cant do in centOS. The step below:

```
sudo a2ensite httpd.conf
```

When I search for the equivalent of this command in centOS there is none.

What could be missing in my config?
Could it be that I was not able to reload the `httpd.conf`?

***`***UPDATE***`***

when I try to access using IP like `192.168.1.97/project` When I have the virtual host config I cant access when I comment out the config I can access it.

***`***Update***`***

When I rune `netstat -autnp | grep "\:80" | grep LISTEN`

I get :

> tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      6905/httpd

Comment: Try putting the hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: how should i go with @MichaelHampton sorry not that good with dealing with server

Comment: With an editor? How did you edit it previously?

Comment: I used vi editor i mean what should I add in the hosts file? you mean I should move the file into the folder /etc/hosts? sorry I didnt get the first question I thought I need to add some lines to it @MichaelHampton

Comment: You need to add an IP address and hostname that you want to use.

Comment: I have this `192.168.1.97   www.project.com` in the hosts file that is the IP address of the server and the address will be `www.project.com` i also tried adding `:80` like `192.168.1.97:80   www.project.com` still no result

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing  hxxp://project.com/ but you only have www.project.com in your /etc/hosts file. you need to add an entry for project.con too

```
192.168.1.97   www.project.com project.com
127.0.0.1      www.project.com project.com
```

Comment: what are the last two parameters ?

Comment: still same i cant access it